# HTML5: tablet drawing

Tags: ipad, html, tablet

Does HTML5 have a good way of letting the user draw using a tablet stylus?  By good, I mean mainly: is it usable? does it respond as quickly as a native app (if the browser implementation is good)?

In other words: Is it possible to clone an iPad notepad app in HTML5 in Safari on iPad?

Answer (score 3):

It won't respond quickly as a native app, but it'll respond pretty quickly. To find out for sure, make a [really simple prototype](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/649/example2.html) and test it out!